# How to retrieve Part/BOM from Windchill using Java?

Tags: java, ptc-windchill

My organization has an existing installation of Windchill and PDMLink and we are interested in integrating the Part and BOM data from those systems with third-party systems in the Enterprise. Our intention is to write a Java app that pulls data from Windchill/PDMLink and puts it into the other systems. We don't have a big ERP system, so we're not interested in doing heavy automated connectors -- we just want a simple way to retrieve data from Windchill using it's SOAP webservice.

Unfortunately, I can't find any documentation to get me started. I found some webservice documentation (http://*my-windchill-server*/Windchill/infoengine/jsp/tools/doc/index.jsp) but I don't know how to go about calling that webservice. Could somebody help point me in the right direction?

- How do I do a simple SOAP call to retrieve information from Windchill?
- If I get the Windchill installation files, is there an API or something I can include in my Java project?
- Is there somewhere I can find sample code for this scenario?

Any help would be appreciate and I'm happy to clarify or provide further information if necessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I am NOT sure what Windchill version you used, and what OS your Windchill based on.

1. Answer for Q1. Please google windchill info-engine for the SOAP
2. Answer for Q2. If you already installed windchill, please under system variable **WT_HOME**/codebase to build a codebase.jar and collect all the java files and jar together, and import the codebase.jar into IDE tools, to check the API.
3. Answer for Q3. If you install windchill under Windows system, there is a way to get all the documentations under **WT_HOME**, please search *.pdf under. There are many reference doc under the directory(For my, it is OK to find them on Windchill 9.1 with Windows OS).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the WSDL file of the web service to generate your Java classes with the wsimport tool.
Most of the classes are self-explaining.
You don't need any Windchill libraries .